# PrimeNg rows doesn't expand after update on angular 8.1.3 and primeng 8.0.2

Tags: angular, primeng, angular8

I have updated my angular application to an new version (anugular 8.1.3 and PrimeNg 8.0.2). All things are working except the expanded rows in my PrimeNg p-table.

I have tried to follow the example from primeng https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowexpansion
but it seems not to help. What I want is, that the rows should expand after the data is loaded as an default.

```html
<p-table [value]="regelklassenJahrgaenge" dataKey="jahrgangName" [expandedRowKeys]="expandedJahrgaenge">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr class="header">
                <th class="legend-cell name-column">Klassenname</th>
                <th class="legend-cell">Anzahl Schüler</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-jahrgang let-expanded="expanded">
            <tr>
                <td class="expandable-cell" colspan="12">
                    <a href="#" class="expandable-link" [pRowToggler]="jahrgang">
                        <mat-icon *ngIf="expanded">expand_less</mat-icon>
                        <mat-icon *ngIf="!expanded">expand_more</mat-icon>
                        {{jahrgang.jahrgangName}}
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-jahrgang>
            <tr *ngFor="let klasse of jahrgang.klassen; first as isFirst, index as i" [formGroup]="klasse.formValues">
                <!-- Klassenname -->
                <td class="legend-cell"> {{klasse.klassenname}} </td>
                <!-- Anzahl Schüler in Klasse -->
                <td class="edit-cell" first>
                   Test
                </td>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

```js
export class RegelklasseTableComponent implements OnChanges {

    @Input() regelklassenJahrgaenge: RegelklassenJahrgangForm[];

    expandedJahrgaenge: { [key: string]: number } = {};

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (this.regelklassenJahrgaenge) {
            this.setAllJahrgaengeExpanded();
        }
    }

    private setAllJahrgaengeExpanded(): void {
        this.regelklassenJahrgaenge.forEach((jahrgang: RegelklassenJahrgangForm) => {
            this.expandedJahrgaenge[jahrgang.jahrgangName] = 1;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this code:

```
private setAllJahrgaengeExpanded(): void {
    this.regelklassenJahrgaenge.forEach((jahrgang: RegelklassenJahrgangForm) => {
        this.expandedJahrgaenge[jahrgang.jahrgangName] = 1;
    });
}
```

Here we say that it should be filled with 1 and the the number stands for true.
I needed to update this code:

```
private setAllJahrgaengeExpanded(): void {
    this.regelklassenJahrgaenge.forEach((jahrgang: RegelklassenJahrgangForm) => {
        this.expandedJahrgaenge[jahrgang.jahrgangName] = true;
    });
}
```

The number **1** is now **true**.
And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I used colspan in the td tag like this:

`<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-plan>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <p-tabView>`

where 6 is the number of columns.